# Recommended json data structure to store chat log in a text file

Tags: json, cordova, data-structures

I have a chat app where I need to store chat log for individual contacts. Currently I am using plain array like below to store in a .txt file

```
var messages = [{_id:1, message : "Hello"}, {_id:$1, message : "Hello", }];
```

I can see below problems with it if it grows bigger.

1. While retrieving back it takes so much processing to convert it back to array from txt format.
2. Takes so much cache memory.

But, I feel it simplifies Searching messages. Would like to know if there are better alternatives to this structure.

Note : The reason for preferring .txt file over indexedDB or webSQL is I do not want to deal with storage limitations.

Comment: How do you read and write to this text file that's (presumably) on the client?

Comment: @Pointy I am using this inside Cordova app. Using File API I am able to do this. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: OK that helps a lot - I added the tag.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks. Could you please suggest some ways to do this.

Comment: Use a database instead.

Comment: @PHPglue Please look at the note in my question. I am not using DB as they pose some storage limits

Comment: It may be applicable for any *language*, but storing things in text files is impossible for a web application. You should have as many tags as possible on your question to attract attention from knowledgeable people.

Comment: @Pointy Hmmm, I agree with you and from now I follow your suggestion. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

You can remove words `_id` and `message` and store plain `array` `[id, message]` instead of `object` in that way you will reduce your file size. You can read files from ending by chunks while search. You can store search indexes in separate file.

**UPDATE:**

So your file will be:

```
[[1,'message1'],[2,'message2'],[1,'message3']]
```

It will be much shorter then with keys and if you have static schema - no problem to parse it:

```
var file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('filepath.txt'));
for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
    messages.push({id: file[i][0], message: file[i][1]};
}
```

After little thinking, I guess it will be better to separate files by date `2014-10-26.txt` and search in them one by one and you can stream output via socket while searching, so user will get immediate output.

If you don't care that much about RAM, you can even cache files in variables to prevent often `read` from HDD  and set TTL on cache expire to get rid of not used files for a while. This way you will not get that much memory used.

Comment: It shouldn't change much when gzipped however.

Comment: Can you please add an example?

Comment: @monkeyinsight Thanks for the example. But the problem if I make it based on dates, sometimes I may delete a single message from file. In such case it will become empty(?)

Comment: @redV no, you can write recent messages in memory and let users edit them for 3 minutes (like in Skype) after that time messages become uneditable and you write them in file

Comment: @monkeyinsight In skype also, after 3 minutes messages can removed.

Comment: @redV no :) but if you want to enable this feature, you need to read file, remove message from there and overwrite file again with content without this message. Need to be aware of new messages write, so you need to postpone all writes to this file

Comment: At this point, you've gotten pretty close to writing your own simple database app. There are instructions online for how to program simple text file based databases.

Comment: Arrays of arrays are generally a bad code smell.  JavaScript arrays are ordered lists, so you don't need `id` fields unless you are referencing them elsewhere, in which case you can use the index.

Answer (score 3):

I gather from some of the discussion that your 'json text file' will be stored using File API, so there is a definite limit on filesize as opposed to some server where you could assume almost 'infinite' storage. So, you will eventually have to limit the number of messages and contacts.

Since this is a 'chat log', I assume you need to preserve the order of messages and users to be able to display a chat history (if you only wanted to store all messages from individual users, the answer would be quite different.)

So, you are stuck with storing `{userid:XXX, message:"YYY"}` in a fixed order.

As *monkeyinsight* suggests, using JSON this will be smallest as an array: `[XXX,"YYY"]`

To answer your concerns: 1. amount of processing and 2. storage space, it would be possible to store blocks of these messages in separate files along with an index

```
var message_index["msg001.json","msg002.json", ... ];
```

where each file contains, say, 1000 messages as

```
var messages=[[userid,message], ...];
```

allowing you to drop the oldest file from message_index when you run out of storage or whatever.

The actual files can be reduced in size a little more if you don't save them as JSON and simply use a string, e.g.

```
var messages=":1:message one:2:message two:3:another message:4:last message";

var getMsg= function( id, msgs ){
    var key= ":"+id+":";
    var ikey= msgs.search(key);
    var message={'id':id, 'message':""};
    if( ikey >= 0 ){
        var start= ikey+key.length;
        var end= msgs.indexOf(":", start );
        if( end > start ){
            message.message= msgs.substr(start, end-start); 
        }else{ 
            message.message= msgs.substr(start); 
        }
    }
    return message;
}

var m= getMsg(4, messages);   // returns: {id: 4, message: "last message"}
```

saving 4 characters per entry (e.g.":1:a" vs "[1,'a']," )

You would, of course, have to ensure that the separator (':' in this example) did not occur in a message.